# ffmpeg- is there any limitation on number of drawtext filter used per command?

Tags: ffmpeg

i have to write different text on a number of images. The final filter command is quite large (> 500 draw text filters in a single command). I am writing this to a text file and using filter_complex_script to read it.
If the number of frames and filter is small, it is working fine, but for a configuration with large number of images and draw text filters, it fails. Error is:

```
Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'enable=between(n,180,180):fontsize=28:fontfile=C\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf:fontcolor=0x000000:text=109.0:x=581:y=527-th'
Error initializing complex filters.
No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try enclosing the font file in single quotes. I need to, at the command line.

Comment: in the command it is already enclosed in single quotes. eg: drawtext=enable='between(n,177,177)':fontsize=28:fontfile='C\:/Windows/Fonts/Arial.ttf':fontcolor='0x000000':text='109.0':x=581:y=527. If i run just this one it works fine.

Comment: Sounds like you have a misplaced quote somewhere. Try duplicating one good drawtext string 500 times and check if it's really a matter of filterchain length.

Comment: I duplicated the same drawtext filter around 630 times, got the same error again. For around 500 it is working fine.

Comment: Is the same text ever repeated?

Comment: Yes.But still if number of images and the text that needs to be written is more, the number of drawtext filter used would increase.

Comment: Hi. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Yes. You can use an app such as Aegisub to create the text as subtitles. You can individually position, style and time each text. Save as .ASS. When ready, run `-vf subtitles=file.ass`

Comment: @Gyan After a lot of research, your option is the best. Thank you so much